# Adding text to the end of the mail sent from shell script

Tags: email, shell, solaris

```
mailbody="${mailbody}${chk}% ${fs}\n \n Thanks and Regards,\n Myname"
```

I want to insert my name and "thanks" at the end of the mail.
I declared variables separately. When I try it, it is coming together with every `fs` in the server rather than at the end of the mail. E.g.:

> thanks and regards, myname / 70%
>       thanks and regards, myname /tmp 36%